# How to Install Microsoft SQL Server in Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04

Please How do I Install SQL server in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I a new Ubuntu user and I need the sql server for Database class.  I had to partition my hard drive and use windows to be able to use the Sql server.  I want to install in in the Ubuntu

Comment: well if its mysql ... then its `sudo apt install mysql-server` if its microsoft sql (MSsql) then  not sure if that can be ran through wine (windows emulator) but .. if not .. then you are still tied to Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft have a set of instructions and link to their PPA at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu for installing MSSQL on a Ubuntu system.
The instructions dont work so well with 17.04, but haven't run into problems with 16.04 (I've installed it on 3 servers at the office.)

Update:
Yeah, the terminal isn't the easiest to getting to know your way around. Stick with it, the more you use it - the easier it gets.

I've used a couple of editors in Ubuntu to connect with MSSQL databases that are straightforward to install.
[Atom.io](https://atom.io/) is a generally useful editor with a good selection of SQL packages available to install. 
Microsoft's [Visual Code code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download) has quite a few useful SQL connection and query extensions available too.

HTH

Comment: This works for me, Thank you. There is just a little problem,  I can only use it in the terminal and am not that great with the terminal commands.

Comment: Hi, I 've updated the answer with a suggestion